# terminate user by session and cookie(auth_key)

Tags: yii2, terminate

I want to terminate user that login using one username , I save session in mongodb and delete session and change auth_key in mysql user table , and that user throw site out.But have problem , when I change auth key all those users who checked remember me , throw site logged out , , I store auth_key in session db mongodb in different way 
at first I save auth key in this way (web.php)

```html
'session' => [
'class' => 'yii\mongodb\Session',
'writeCallback' => function($session)
 {
  return [
          'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
          'agent' => Yii::$app->request->getUserAgent(),
          'ip' => Yii::$app->request->getUserIP(),
          'auth_key' => Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(),
        ];
      }
 ],
```

But this have problem in each refresh of page the auth_key is regenerate ,

Another way i do it , i overwrite method after login but thats have problem some times the auth_key is saved but some times not.

What can I do to avoid this problem ? and what's your suggestion about this way ? Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use auth_key in writeCallback.
It's Regenerate every page refresh.

Comment: expire time is also gets generated on each page refresh, how to stop that?